# phpunit selenium getting header information of the url open

Tags: selenium, header, phpunit

I am using [phpunit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) and [selenium](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html) to write some functional testing for my project. 
What I am looking for is the way to retrieve Response-header

There are some URLs which dont have a `.js` extension but return javascript as the code.

What I am looking for is the header information (especially `content-type`) of the URL opened with `$this->open();` function

For eg:

```
//if I do
$this->open('http://stackoverflow.com');
// or
$this->open('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js')

// and then use some function like
$this->getResponseHeaders();
// returns me array of header information or
// some function just for content type
$this->getContentType();
// which return text/html or text/javascript
```

Is there any way selenium provides this functionality or a hack or a trick to get the details. I went through the selenium documentation and the TestCase files and didnt find anything close to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's sad, but you cannot. It [does not allowed by phpunit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/199) because [it does not allowed by WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141).

> We will not be adding this feature to the WebDriver API as it falls outside of our current 
>   scope (emulating user actions).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question you need these two steps:

```
$this->open('http://stackoverflow.com');
$htmltext = $this->getHtmlSource();
```

and then you can get the inforamtion by splitting the htmltext...

Comment: No basically what i want is the `response header` details with `content-type` information